# Declaring friend insertion operator (operator <<) for nested enum class

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

For a class with a nested enum class, where should the friend operator for the nested enum be declared.  Because it is a friend, it can't be outside the class.  But there is no way to define a friend operator inside a enum class declaration in c++.  So, should it be declared inside the class in which the enum is nested?  This works for both public and private enum declarations

EDIT: Question is this...  is the enclosing class the correct scope for declaring the friend function for a nested enum?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a::b::c
{

class Test
{
private:
    enum class TestEnumPrivate { v0, v1, v2 };

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, TestEnumPrivate const v)
    {
        return os << static_cast < int32_t >(v);
    }

public:
    auto value() const
    {
        return TestEnumPrivate::v0;
    }

    enum class TestEnumPublic { v0, v1, v2 };

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, TestEnumPublic const v)
    {
        return os << static_cast < int32_t >(v);
    }

};

}

int main()
{
    std::cout << a::b::c::Test().value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a::b::c::Test::TestEnumPublic::v0 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "*So, should it be declared inside the class in which the enum is nested?*" What do you mean by "should it"? If that's valid C++, then what's wrong with using it?

Comment: It can be declared inside and defined outside.

Comment: It cannot be declared inside, since the left hand side is an `std::ostream&`, so it would have to be defined inside of `std::ostream`. You cannot extend members of the `std` namespace, so you cannot define this operator as a member function.

Comment: @Khoyo, you can have a `friend` non-member function declaration inside `Test`, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is this... is the enclosing class the correct scope for declaring the friend function for a nested enum?

Yes.

My old answer was correct, but off-topic.
For reference:

Declare your operator as a free-function, not a member of the class - this should always be the case for `operator<<` into a `std::ostream`. If your enum is private, you should also declare this function as a friend of the class.

EDIT:

> Because it is a friend, it can't be outside the class.

I guess this is why you're confused.

A friend declaration can affect outside method of the class.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: It isn't. It's declared as it should be if it was a free function, but inside the class, so it's not a free function.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Maybe it is a free function, but that's a weird way to declare one... Is it even valid?

Anyway, declaring it idiomatically can't hurt.

Comment: Even if it is defined inside a class, it is not a member function. And it is a perfectly valid way to define a friend non-member function.